# Getting failure with the Task Scheduler on Windows Server

Tags: windows, task, scheduler, wsh

I have created a VBS file and prepared a batch file to run that VBS.

The code in a batch file to execute batch is below:

```
CScript "file.vbs"
```

When I ran the file manually, it returns success but if use scheduler, cmd prompt opens, and closes and nothing returned from the scheduler and the final result is (0x1)

Comment: Can you screenshot the task? I imagine you may be setting it to run when the admin account is logged in or something like this.

Comment: It's likely a permission issue due to UAC (User Account Control) requiring an elevated account to execute the Task, check the settings.

Comment: @Suman Task Scheduler failing to execute VBScripts is a very common problem, what research have you done? A [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQQQLvb--7hKSrm0k-nHSK1SkrEVQ%3A1568116969063&ei=6ZB3Xa6_A82GgQaS_JvoAQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+task+scheduler&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+task+scheduler&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1913.5784..5872...0.0..1.186.1392.23j1......0....1..gws-wiz.c3zHdvWMo3M&ved=0ahUKEwju16D3msbkAhVNQ8AKHRL-Bh0Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) will bring back a plethora of results.

Comment: I logged in as an Administrator and created the task @Matthew.

Comment: Provide an _absolute path_ to `file.vbs` like `CScript "absolute path\file.vbs"` (or precede the `CScript "file.vbs"` with `cd /D "absolute path\"`.